# Why can an intransitive verb 出る take an object?

Tags: verbs

Consider the following sentences:

1. ボタンを押すとジュース**が出ます**。
2. ６時に家**を出て**８時に帰ります。

I don't understand why the verb 出る which is an intransitive (as in the first example) can take an object (as in the second example).